# how to update ROS_PACKAGE_PATH?

Tags: rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

farshid@ubuntu:~$ roscreate-pkg farshid

```
WARNING: current working directory is not on ROS_PACKAGE_PATH!
Please update your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable.
```

how update ROS_PACKAGE_PATH ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11639/how-to-update-ros_package_path--?/) by [abrsefid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1260/abrsefid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2011-10-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is described in the tutorial [Installing and Configuring Your ROS Environment](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2011-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aly](https://answers.ros.org/users/20349/aly/) on 2014-09-30**:
if after configuring your environment, still the ros commands like (ros_make) doesn't work than go to .bashrc file & remove all the duplicate lines at the bottom. than follow the instruction mentioned by Dan Lazewatsky.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use this syntax on the command line:

`export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks`

Replace "~/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks" with the desired package path.

---

Originally posted by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) with karma: 353 on 2011-10-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1